# Laplace Transformation of $y''+5y'+6y=2e^{-t}, y(0)=1, y'(0)=3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Laplace Transformation of

$$y''+5y'+6y=2e^{-t}, \quad y(0)=1, y'(0)=3 $$

$$s^2Y(s)-s+5Y(s)=\frac{2}{s+1}+s+8 $$

$$\frac{A}{s+1}+\frac{B}{s+3}+\frac{C}{s+2}=s^2+9s+10 $$

$A=1, B=-4, C=4 $

$$y(t) = e^{-t}-4e^{-3t}+4e^{-2t} $$

Am I right?

Comment: It's **really** difficult to tell without you formatting your text properly... I'd edit it but I can't make heads or tails of some portions. Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you're going to post multiple questions, at least try to learn a little bit of formatting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a typo in the first line or not - your question is very poorly formatted and you skipped a couple steps, but it should be

$$ (s^2 Y - s - 3) + 5(sY - 1) + 6Y = \frac{2}{s+1} $$

$$ \implies (s^2 + 5s+6)Y = \frac{2}{s+1} + s + 8 = \frac{s^2+9s+10}{s+1} $$

Then

$$ Y(s) = \frac{s^2+9s+10}{(s+1)(s+2)(s+3)} = \frac{A}{s+1} + \frac{B}{s+2} + \frac{C}{s+3} $$

I believe the answer is correct.